# MacBook user name I thought I deleted still works for logging in to my account

Tags: macos, user-accounts

I (Katy) am giving my old computer to my husband (Andrew). I mucked it up somehow and now I can log in to the admin Katy account using "Andrew" as the login name and the Katy password, despite Andrew not being a user. I can also log in to Katy using "Katy" as the login name and the Katy password.

When I try to add "Andrew" again as a user account, I get the error "Name is used by another user". But the only users listed ar Katy (admin) and guest.

So "Andrew" is obviously stored as an account somewhere despite me not able to find it and delete it.

What happened? Can I permanently delete "Andrew" and start over so "Katy" isn't the same/connected to "Andrew"?

Mac OSX 10.6.8

Comment: Hi Katy! So, your account is in fact the only one you can log in to (except for the guest)? In your System Preferences, what exactly is listed under *Accounts*? Could you open */Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app*, then enter the following command and provide us with the output by [edit]ing your question? `dscl . read /users/$(whoami) | tail -n 7`

Answer (score 0):

Go here, and make sure to do a backup before you do anything else!

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1428